# How to use CAPSPageMenu source for Objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing IOS project using objective C.
I am going to make sliding tab page.
I found this source from github.
https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

This is the source code which I use CAPSPageMenu.
When

```
@interface BusinessTabViewController ()
@property(nonatomic) CAPSPageMenu* pageMenu;
@end

@implementation BusinessTabViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    UIViewController*controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GongsiyingyeViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.title  = @"Sample title";
    [controllerArray addObject:controller];
    NSDictionary *parameteres = @{CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth:@(4.3), CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl:@(YES), CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight:@(0.1)};
    _pageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:parameteres];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageMenu.view];
}
```

It shows only  white screen.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: The library you mentioned looks good. more than 3k stars. Check your code, you must have forgotten to initialize a view controller.

Comment: It was right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface BusinessTabViewController ()
@property(nonatomic) CAPSPageMenu* pageMenu;
@end

@implementation BusinessTabViewController


-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    UIViewController*controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.title  = @"Sample title1";
    UIViewController*controller1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller1.title  = @"Sample title2";
    UIViewController*controller2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller2.title  = @"Sample title3";
    [controllerArray addObject:controller];
    [controllerArray addObject:controller1];
    [controllerArray addObject:controller2];

    NSDictionary *parameteres = @{
                                  CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth:@(4.3),
                                  CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl:@(YES),
                                  CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight:@(0.1),
                                  CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuHeight:@(40),
                                  CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuMargin:@(20),
                                  CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorHeight:@(2.0)

                                  };
    _pageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:parameteres];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageMenu.view];

}
```

I use viewDidLayoutSubviews() for get accurate the size of frame. 
It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related with PageMenu, Comment the code for Registering  Push Notification then try it.

And Before pushing a viewcontroller check that viewcontroller is nil or not.

CAPSPageMenu is working fine in our project.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right.
I edited this question.
Please see this and help me.
Thanks.

Comment: check the controller is not nil and is it adding fine in that controllerArray. then  try changing the below line           parameters = @{CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemWidthBasedOnTitleTextWidth:@(NO),CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuHeight: @(44.0)

Comment: Thanks. It was my fault. I didn't navigate to correct uiviewcontroller.
Thanks again.

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth'-   error on integrating latest PageMenu(2.0.0) into my Objective C Project.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake I integrated using Pods and it was taking swift version so instead I just integrated the CAPSPageMenu.h and CAPSPageMenu.m manually and used only the Objective C Methods and works well :)

Comment: I have "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth" and also for all CAPSPageMenuOption other items